# Creating Notebook Failed

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

After I successfully deploy a Spark cluster on HDInsight, the Jupyter server is running normally, but if I try to create a notebook I get an error with the message below:

**Creating Notebook Failed
An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
Not Found**

Some weeks ago I noticed it would always happen if I create the cluster with ADLS as the default storage, but it would work fine when creating the cluster with a Blob store as the default storage. Now even this option is not working anymore.

It seems like it cannot find the Kernel on container, as there is just an empty file called HDINotebooks rather than a folder called HDINotebooks with the kernels inside.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Regards,
Fabio

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by Microsoft support, I am posting the answer here in case someone come across this issue.

When we have a HDInsight cluster within a VNET, we must access Jupyter (as well as Livy and other services) directly on the active head node, rather than trying to go through the gateways.